# data type not understood

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I'm trying to use a matrix to compute stuff. The code is this

```
import numpy as np
# some code
mmatrix = np.zeros(nrows, ncols)
print mmatrix[0, 0]
```

but I get 'data type not understood', and it works if I do it from terminal.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Try:

```
mmatrix = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
```

Since the shape parameter has to be an int or sequence of ints

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Otherwise you are passing `ncols` to `np.zeros` as the dtype.